# @ModelAttribute populate form field from request param instead of backing form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, modelattribute

My problem is:
@ModelAttribute populate form field from request param instead of form DTO if request param and form field has same name.

Example: I have form with input filed called `name`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Given form with value name=John,
If I submit form (web method POST) using url:
`http://localhost:8080/user/?name=Michael`
I will have query param and form field that has same name.
What I expect is: name field should be populated from Form Field, not query params.

MyForm.java

```
public class MyForm {
    private String name;
    private Boolean isMale;
    private Byte status;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Boolean getIsMale() {
        return isMale;
    }
    public void setIsMale(Boolean isMale) {
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }
    public Byte getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(Byte status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

MyController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String index(
        Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("form") MyForm form,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {
    String name = form.getName(); //this contains value from form: Michael
    Boolean isMale = form.getIsMale(); //this contains value from query parameter: true
    Byte status= form.getStatus(); //this contains value from form: 1
    return "views/index";
}
```

When I submit the form with values:

```
name = Michael
isMale = false
status = 1
```

using url with query params:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/?isMale=true
```

then `isMale` will contains value `true`, that populate from query param.

What I expects is, `isMale` should contains `false` that populate from Form Field.
How to solve this problem...?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequestBody` annotation instead of `@ModelAttribute` if you want just the request body (which contains your form data) to populate your Java object

*(as a side note, its bad design to pass the same parameter name in both your query string as well as in your form data. Do refactor, if possible)*

Comment: Actually, index() method will have @RequestMapping with method POST and GET:
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }). So, if user visit `http://localhost:8080/user/?name=Michael` he will have form with name initialized (Michael), then he may change name value to Jonh and submit the form.